not able to download qr code from sharepoint list in form of a image but giving link of the qr code
I have a SharePoint list that contains a column with barcode URLs. When I export this list to CSV, the URLs are exported, but I want the actual barcode images to be included in the CSV instead of the URLs.
Here is an example of the URLs I have in my SharePoint list:https://example.com/barcode/12345
When I export to CSV, I get the URL, but I would like the CSV to contain the barcode image in base64 or any other image format.
Has anyone achieved this or can guide me on how to modify the export process to include the images directly in the CSV?When I export to CSV, I get the URL, but I would like the CSV to contain the barcode image in base64 or any other image format.
When I export to CSV, I get the URL, but I would like the CSV to contain the barcode image in base64 or any other image format.
I am expecting the barcodes in image format in the CSV when downloading from the SharePoint list. For instance, instead of:

Your barcode link does not work. Please insert the picture here.
